# Do Office 365(word, excel, power-point) support Office dialog API?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-dialog-api

Office dialog API with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() opens a dialog (verified in Office 2021 version). Do Office 365 supports same API or any other to show a dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same API is used for opening a dialog in desktop applications as well as O365 (browsers). Read more about dialog APIs in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

You may also find the [Best practices and rules for the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices) page helpful.